# Django Rest/Ember How to connect to models

Tags: django, ember.js, django-rest-framework

I am getting started with Ember, and Django Rest Framework and I can't seem to peice together how to connect a model so that Ember can use the data in that model and create a simple drop down box. I have one model that I am starting with that is as such:

```
id
name
security
status
```

All I want to achieve is allowing Ember to use the data in this model and create a dropdown like so.

```
<select id="model">
   <option value="model.ID">model.Name</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am complete new to Ember and Django Rest.

Comment: There is also a project to bridge the gap between the format of django rest framework and ember-data: https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter

Comment: I am having some trouble using that adapter.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154265/assertion-failed-no-model-was-found-for-0-django-rest-and-ember-adapter

Comment: Have you checked out the example app linked in the projects readme? If you're still having trouble definitely post a question on stack overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into a ton of detail, I've created a mini example of what you're looking for

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/Ozimatuj/2/edit

You'll note that I'm using mockjax, so instead of hitting any real endpoint, it's all mocked.  Additionally I'd recommend using a client side record management solution (such as ember-data or ember-model).  That's another discussion though.

In the application route (which correlates with the root of your app) it hits the model hook (which should return the model associated with that route.  I'm returning a POJO of the users.  That model is being assigned as the content of the application controller (automatically generated).  The the application template is being built, and it's being backed by the application controller.  Inside the application template we create an instance of ember select, and we tell it that the content backing it is model (which is the model/content in the application controller).  We also say, use bind the user model (you could do id) and the name to the value and the label respectively.

I then bound the value of the select to selectedPerson, so anytime the value changes, the selectedPerson updates, the template which talks about that person will update.  Magic.  Ember does the rest.

This is a really broad question, so if you have any other questions, please ask a specific question, and I'd really recommend going through the getting started guide, it's really short, but will give you a decent foundation of terminology and methodology of Ember.  http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/

For Ember Data I'd do a quick read the of the transition document for ED 1.0 beta.
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

```
DS.DjangoRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend();
DS.DjangoRESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  defaultSerializer: "DS/djangoREST"
});
```

Comment: I get where your going and thank you for the bin, but I'm still unsure of how you take the DjangoRESTAdapter and use it in your example...

Comment: DjangoRestAdapter is used with Ember Data, the client side framework.

Comment: Great, so now I see the ajax request and the select box is filling in as expected. Thanks again for your help.